# Is there a way to progressively subtract the quantity of same item on different cells and keep track of it?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I try to better explain the problem using this screenshot as example:

[image: example]

As you can see from the screenshot, what's going here is the following:

- When an item is received, it is put on column G with the actual quantity received. Also an OrderID is associated to the item.
- Everytime an item is shipped, it is put in column A.

What I would like to achieve?

***Everytime I ship an item, I would like to progressively subtract the quantity in column B to the first non-zero quantity in column H (corresponding to the same item I just put).***

If I would be able to create a list ( as in C++) the pseudo code would be the following:

```
item = $A2;
While(item =/= blank){
 If(QuantityReceived > 0 && item == ItemReceived)
  QuantityReceived--;  ' here I just decrement by 1, because default quantity shipped is 1
 else {
  ItemReceived = ItemReceived -> next;
  QuantityReceived = QuantityReceived -> next;  
 }
ItemReceived = $G2;
QuantityReceived = $H2;
item = item -> next;
}
```

I wrote this code to explain what I would like to achieve.

Do you have any tips/solution/ideas?

Hope I explained the problem well.

Thanks.

Comment: Please update your screenshot to include date columns, both for shipments and receipts - the 'quantity left' will obviously vary by date, but your current screenshot omits this critical aspect

Comment: Why do they need to include anything to do with dates? They just want the first non-zero value of corresponding item to lose the new value submitted in column B. It's not an easy setup to deal with but I don't see why this particular question has the need for dates.

Comment: As @jamheadart said, the date isn't a critical aspect. The goal here is just to update the "What's left" value everytime an item is shipped

Comment: I cannot understand too much related to what try accomplishing against the picture you show... I think, what you try explaining in words must match the the situation in the picture. Is the picture you show the initial situation? Why do you need a, so named, 'Default value'? How do you want operating many received quantities with many shipments? Do you want firstly decreasing the first received order? Don't you want keeping the total existing quantity per each item? In any situation what you show us does not match your explanation regarding what you need... How subtracting 'in column B'?

Comment: @FaneDuru I want progressively decreasing the remaining quantity in column H for each item has been shipped. That said, I don't need to know what is the OrderID the item belongs, so I just decrement the first non-zero item (information stored in column H) has been shipped (column B, that by default the quantity is 1, don't need to handle a shipment of  a bulk). Let me know if you need more informations and sorry for not being able to explain well :(

Comment: This explanation looks strange, too (for me)? I mean, from logistic point of view... If something will go wrong in calculations, how will you correct it if no any transability exists? It does not look a very inspired idea to diminish the received quantity... In my opinion you should operate in column "What's left", **where to keep the total amount of the same item per each row**. I mean, if receiving twice for "item A" you should have in J3 **and** J5 the same amount: `(10 + 2) - (1 + 1 + 1) = 9`. I mean for the existing situation. Then applying the same rule for each shipment/Receiving...

Comment: No offence, don't worry. I wanted to keep the logistic POV out from the request.
I don't want to have a single sum of total left item, for each item. Why? Because I want to approximately trace what's left of each order. For example:

If I order 3x item_A day 1, then I order 2x item_A on day 4, I have 2 different orders ID.
If I deliver 4x item_A, someday, I ""know"" that I have no more any item_A from orderID of day 1 and one has been used too from the order on day 4.

Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: Then, what should " I don't need to know what is the OrderID the item belongs" mean? I also asked "Do you want firstly decreasing the first received order? " and you did not confirm it... So, **I wish you succes in solving your problem!** It does not look too logic,  and I consider I spent enough time to clarify it according to my way of thinking/understanding. But I can admit that maybe I am tired and not able to understand your logic...

Comment: Sure, I admit I am not so good to explain, I am sorry for that. To asnwer your question:
1) I don't need to know exactly which item (for real) came from one order or another one.
2) I want decrease the first received order and if it's zero, then decreased the 2nd one and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in the code for the sheet (not a module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'restrict to users entering data in column B and only one cell
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Cells.Column = 2 Then
        ' get the item name depending on removed or add
        If Target.Value = 1 Then
            itemName = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value
            amt = -1
        ElseIf Target.Value = 0 Then
            itemName = ws.Range("A" & Target.Row).Value
            amt = 1
        Else
            End
        End If
        ' set up rng then look through all of the items in column G
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Range("G1:G" & Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            ' look for the item and a whats left of more than 0
            If rng.Value = itemName And rng.Offset(0, 3) > 0 Then
                rng.Offset(0, 3) = rng.Offset(0, 3) + amt
                ws.Columns("A:B").Clear
                
                lastrow = Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Row
                ws.Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value = Range("A1:B" & lastrow).Value
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                End
            End If
            
        Next rng
        ' message if item with positive left not found
            MsgBox ("no item remaining found")
    End If
End Sub
```

test and let me know how you get on / accept the answer if it works well for what you want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it works fine when I put some item on column A (with quantity on B), but if  I delete an item that I wrongly put in there, the values on column J aren't updated ( so the one I decremented before isn't added again ). Is there any way to fix this? Thanks again for the effort

Comment: the easiest way I can do this is if we can use another sheet as a reference, would this be possible for your situation?  the sheet could be hidden from users but we need a reference for what was in the cell before

Comment: Sure, actually even the fields QuantityReceived and QuantityShipped are on different sheet, but I just asked for help what I wanted to achieve is possible or not. If is better for you to use multiple sheets there is not any problem.

Comment: have edited you'll need a sheet called "Reference", less confident on this but also you will only be able to clear one cell at a time.  check and see what you think.  let me know if it does the job.  (oh yeah and start by adding an item not removing one, that wont work)

Comment: I tried to use the code you edited, but it seems not working, unfortunately. I started adding item, but it doesn't update values on the "what's left" column

Comment: so that bit i did actually test was working and is working on my mock up.  have you copied this in the original sheet and then put a new item in column a and then 1 in column b?

Comment: Yes, I put a new item in column A and then 1 in column B, but it doesn't update any value in column J

Comment: I actually see that it work when I add the code the first time. Then if I close and re-open the workbook it doesn't work anymore. It opens in "Design Mode", so the macro isn't allowed. Now all is working, thank you!

Comment: great glad i could help - you can probably make this a little better over time, use it and learn what annoys you about it and how you'd like it to be better!